# getting formatted column value in postgres

Tags: postgresql, split

I have a column in my table having values of format:

```
COURSE_214/MODULE_5825/SUBMODULE_123/..../GOAL_124/ACTIVITY_125.
```

I need value for goal i.e 124 from goal_124. I am planning to use 'regexp_split_to_array' but don't know how to use elements from array.

I am using postgres 9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split_part` like so:

```
select split_part(split_part('COURSE_214/MODULE_5825/SUBMODULE_123/..../GOAL_124/ACTIVITY_125', '/GOAL_', 2), '/', 1)
i.e.
select split_part(split_part(fieldname, '/GOAL_', 2), '/', 1)

Result:
124
```

Comment: Thanks.... suppose there are multiple 'GOAL_' fields...then how to get it? json_object won't work for me as I am using postgres 9.2

Answer (score 1):

Using [`json_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html):

```
select json_object(string_to_array(translate(params, '_', '/'), '/'))
from test

                                          json_object                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"COURSE" : "214", "MODULE" : "5825", "SUBMODULE" : "123", "GOAL" : "124", "ACTIVITY" : "125"}
(1 row)

select json_object(string_to_array(translate(params, '_', '/'), '/'))->>'GOAL' as goal
from test

 goal 
------
 124
(1 row)
```

The column has a format suitable for json. I would suggest to change the type of the column to `jsonb`. The first query may be used as a converter.
After the conversion you would access the parameters in an easy way, e.g.:

```
select *
from test
where params->>'COURSE' = '214'
and (params->>'GOAL')::int > 120;
```

---

Simple select of all `GOAL_` parameters (if there are more than one)

```
select ltrim(elem, 'GOAL_')
from (
    select unnest(string_to_array(params, '/')) elem
    from test
    ) sub
where elem like 'GOAL_%'
```

Comment: That's a very nice use of json in combination with string_to_array and translate

Comment: This is not working for me. string_to_array() function is returning results of the form: {COURSE,249,MODULE,6312,GOAL,9059,ACTIVITY,8774,ACTIVITY,8800}.  When I am passing it to json_object(), I am getting the error : ' function json_object(text[]) does not exist'

Comment: To use `json_object()` you need Postgres 9.3+ (for the `jsonb` type - 9.4+).

Comment: Ok... can you suggest how to do in postgres 9.2? we can have multiple GOAL_ in the string

Comment: In 9.2 you could use `hstore`. However my solution assumes unique keys. Perhaps it would be worthwhile to ask a new question with the detailed description of the parameters structure (Postgres version should be always included in a question).

Comment: I've added a simple query to find all `goal_` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using regular expressions, getting the string between slashes

```
select substring(your_column from '^.*/(.*)/.*$') from your_table
```

If you expect to find in that part the GOAL value, use

```
select substring(your_column from '/GOAL_(.*)/') from your_table
```